# Can't edit configurable product page from admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, admin-panel

I cannot expand the **categories** inside the **configurable product** page; all tab take **100% width** and I can't expand them.

The content of the tab is present inside the page (attached image) and is associated with a `display:none` rule. If I remove `display:none` I can see all the products data, also attributes and associate products.

It seems that the page doesn't load all the button at the top of the page. The console then give a 500 error. This problem is for configurable product only, simple product are ok.

[image]

Comment: EDIT: error_log give `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getIsWysiwygEnabled() on a non-object in /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Helper/Form/Wysiwyg.php on line 67`